# Who betrayed Arianne Martell?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Feast for Crows*, Arianne Martell makes a plan to crown Myrcella. Their plan involves taking Myrcella to a safe place. But in the middle of their journey, they are caught by Areo Hotah and his team. When Arianne asks who betrayed her, Hotah tells that someone always tells.

Who is this betrayer? Is anything revealed in a later book?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arianne believes it was either

1. [Ser Andrey Dalt](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Andrey_Dalt)
2. [Garin](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Garin_(orphan))
3. [Sylva Santagar](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sylva_Santagar)

> Someone told, she thought. Someone told. Garin, Drey, and Spotted Sylva were friends of her girlhood, as dear to her as her cousin Tyene. She could not believe they would inform on her... but that left only Darkstar, and if he was the betrayer, why had he turned his sword on poor Myrcella? He wanted to kill her instead of crowning her, he said as much at Shandystone. He said that was how I'd get the war I wanted. But it made no sense for Dayne to be the traitor. If Ser Gerold had been the worm in the apple, why would he have turned his sword upon Myrcella?
>
> Someone told. Could it have been Ser Arys? Had the white knight's guilt won out over his lust? Had he loved Myrcella more than her and betrayed his new princess to atone for his betrayal of the old? Was he so ashamed of what he'd done that he threw his life away at the Greenblood rather than live to face dishonor?
>
> <sup>*A Feast for Crows - The Princess In The Tower*</sup>

Arys and Darkstar are ruled as their actions would not have suited the motive. The other three were not punished for their involvement in the plot. However, we have no further clues as to which one specifically did it.

> "You might have, but you didn't. Dayne, Dalt, Santagar... no, you would never dare make enemies of such Houses."
>
> "I dare more than you dream . . . but leave that for the nonce. Ser Andrey has been sent to Norvos to serve your lady mother for three years. Garin will spend his next two years in Tyrosh. From his kin amongst the orphans, I took coin and hostages. Lady Sylva received no punishment from me, but she was of an age to marry. Her father has shipped her to Greenstone to wed Lord Estermont. As for Arys Oakheart, he chose his own fate and met it bravely. A knight of the Kingsguard . . . what did you do to him?"
>
> <sup>*A Feast for Crows - The Princess In The Tower*</sup>